# Many to Many table in Django not working

Tags: django, django-models

My models.py contains a model that contains two foreign keys:

```
class TestcaseHasCategory(models.Model):
    testcase_idtestcase = models.ForeignKey(Testcase, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Testcase_idTestcase')  # Field name made lowercase.
    Category_idCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Category_idCategory')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'testcase_has_category'
        unique_together = (('testcase_idtestcase', 'Category_idCategory'),)
```

In Django shell printing the objects of that table gives me this output:

```
>>> TestcaseHasCategory.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in _
_repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in _
_iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1087, in
_fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __
iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 83
5, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in
execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 11
0, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defau
lterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'testcase_has_category.id' in 'fiel
d list'")
```

My other models are printable, only the many to many relation is giving issues. Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't migrated your database properly.

Comment: I wiped my database, cleared the migrations folder, called "python manage.py makemigrations" and "python manage.py migrate". Did not solve my problem.

Comment: So I guess it's expecting the table to have a primary key, but this is a Many to Many table, of two ForeignKeys, so there is and should not be a Primary Key... cant Django handle such tables? ugh..

Comment: If you have the ability to wipe your database, why are you setting managed=False? Why not let Django manage your db, and create ids where it needs to?

Comment: setting managed=True did not resolve my issue, also used the "python manage.py migrate" command right after, same error.

Comment: had to ALTER my sql table to add an primary key to make it work for now, is there no smoother way?